# LVL install with old notched ceiling joists

Tags: joists, beam

Down here in Atlanta. Installed an 18' LVL to join two living rooms in my 1960s brick ranch. Used joist hangers on most of the 2"x8" ceiling joists, but there is a small number of joists from the previous doorway that spanned roughly 5'. The ceiling joists in this section were notched and rested on a ledger. I've reached out to the engineer who provided my original recommendation letter for permitting, but haven't heard back for some time. I also reached out the County inspection supervisor and I'm awaiting his feedback/recommendation.

I'm wondering if I can glue and screw a block shim in the ceiling joist notched from the ledger then hang the modified joist in a joist hanger fastened to the new LVL, or if I should sister a new joist at the end of the notched joist and fasten the new sister joist end to the LVL with a hanger. The existing ceiling joists are ~12' on both sides. I'm also wondering what is the appropriate length of the new sistered joists, I've read any where from 3' to 2/3 the length of the original joist.

[image]

Comment: So the notched joists originally spanned 5 feet, but how they span 12 feet?  If the span is still 5 feet, then I would just use a smaller joist hangar that would fit up into the notch.

Answer (score 1):

The Code limits notching at end bearing locations to not exceed 1/4 the depth of the joists.

(See IBC 2308.8.2)

If the notch does not exceed this dimension, you can merely install a joist hanger in the notch fastening it to the joist and then fasten it to the LVL.

Answer (score 0):

The joist notch affects the bearing strength. So I suggest building back as shown below. You shall make sure there are no defects in the makeup block, then use wood adhesive to glue it to the joist. Install the metal hanger once the glue has dried and the block is firmly in place.

[image]

Note: There is a chance you won't need to do anything. However, you need to identify the hanger beside the notch (marked ?), whether it is adequate structurally.

**ADD:**

[image]

The buildup will allow the joist to deliver the designed load to the beam with less stress in the joist at the connection.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see where the makeup block is going to strengthen the existing notched joist, no matter how much glue is used.

Answer (score 0):

Just take an LVL and rip it down to the height you need to fill that void.  Secure that ripped LVL to the beam in place, along it's entire length.  This creates a ledger for those floor joist to rest on.  You will no longer need any joist hanger brackets.  The shear loads have been addressed.  If you need more room to install the LVL ripper then increase the notch to 1.75" and the LVL will drop right in.